# PWA does not have a full-screen when installed from the Play Store but works fine when being added from the browser

Tags: reactjs, frontend, progressive-web-apps, manifest

So i made a PWA APP using reacT.js for the frontend and have managed to put the app on playstore. The problem is that when the app is installed from Playstore or just by sending the APK, it shows the browser address bar. But if i just add the web app from the browser using the add to home screen function it removes the address bar and opens it like a native app.

```
{
  "name": "dama",
  "short_name": "dama",
  "theme_color": "#ff4c01",
  "background_color": "#2C2C37",
  "display": "standalone",
  "permissions": ["fullscreen"],
  "orientation": "portrait",
  "scope": "/",
  "start_url": "/",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable"
    },
    {
      "src": "1024.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "any"
    },
    {
      "src": "maskable.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo256.png",
      "sizes": "256x256",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo384.png",
      "sizes": "384x384",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "description": "Join the fun at Dama! Challenge your friends or try your hand at playing against our smart AI. Experience endless hours of fun as you strategize to capture all your opponent's pieces and win the game."
}
```

I tried researching for possible solutions like adding  "permissions":

```
["fullscreen"],
```

and

````
"android": {
    "theme_color": "#ff4c01",
    "package_name": "com.example.dama"
  }
```  to the manifest file, and it still does not work.  Does anyone have a solution for this ?
````